# Could Ext JS use a store is not attached to grid to render the grid column?

Tags: extjs

When I run this sample, it causes a error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined", the problem is the sotre1 is 0 length when rendering the column,but I can't find a solution to solve this. The scenario may be unreasonable, but I just want to use the unattached store to render the grid column, is there a method to ensure the store1 loaded before rendering the column? 
Here is code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.define('File', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'pid']   
});
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'File',
    //fields: ['id', 'name', 'pid'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'file.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'files',  
            successProperty: 'success'  
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'File',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'file.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'files',  
            successProperty: 'success'  
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'File info',
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {
            header: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },
        {
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'   
        },
        {
            header: 'ParentName',
            dataIndex: 'pid',
            renderer: function(pid){
                var index = store1.find('id', pid); // find it's parent
                console.log(index);
                var name = store1.getAt(index).get('name');
                return name;
            }
        }
    ]
});

});
```

Here is the json file:

```
{
success: true,
files: [
    {id: 1, name: 'root', pid: 1},
    {id: 2, name: 'sub1', pid: 1},
    {id: 3, name: 'sub2', pid: 1},
    {id: 4, name: 'sub1-1', pid: 2},
    {id: 5, name: 'sub1-2', pid: 2}
]   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to flatten the structure on the server side and send parent name along with each child record.

another thing i noticed your stores are identical, why not just use 1?

Comment: It’s really the same,but I just want to use the store which is not attached to the grid to render the grid's column(store1 in this demo)

Comment: why can't you use the same store?

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue related the async nature of AJAX calls, so store1 could not be loaded when you access to its records.

You can try to place the Ext.create inside the callback of store1.load() call:

```
store1.load({
    callback: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', ...);
    }
});
```